# remove <?xml version="1.0" ?> using xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I am generating XML files using `xml.dom.minidom`. Every time I generate a file on the very row there appears `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` and the generated file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <Root>
     data 
 </Root>
```

is not there anyway so have an output without  and my output should look like

```
 <Root>
      data 
 </Root>
```

Comment: You may want to review the samples that you have posted.

Comment: yeah i have just done

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to remove this? The XML declaration is necessary in the worst case and completely harmless in the best case.

Comment: actually i am generating some files for a mob. comm. gateway and that's configured to read it without that, it gives an error this way

Comment: @G.Jan whats wrong with copying the file without the first line?

Comment: @Gusdor i have answered in previous comment. i have been searching for different modules but couldnot find any solution.

Comment: @G.Jan What language are you using?

Comment: @Gusdor i am using Python

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found was to write out `.childNodes[0]`, i.e. write out:

```
doc.childNodes[0].toprettyxml()
```

to the file, which will omit the xml version tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy just to trim the first line from the file, use this code;

```
f = open( 'file.txt', 'r' )
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open( 'file.txt'.'w' )
f.write( '\n'.join( lines[1:] ) )
f.close()
```

Comment: i had tried to read the first row using the .readlines/readline methods but it gives me the root

Answer (score 0):

This does the job where old_data is the xml to strip

`new_data = old_data[old_data.find("?>")+2:]`